# How to check branches in the same project but in different computer?

Tags: git

I am working on a project where I have 3 branches

```
master

second-branch

third-branch
```

now, for the very first time I will be working in the same project but in a different computer.

I just cloned the project, and I did:

```
$ git branch
```

and all I see is `master` branch, and the same with `$ git fetch`, so, how can I check the other branches I've been working on in the first computer where I cloned the project?

Comment: `git branch` only ever shows your local branches.  What does `git branch -r say`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `git branch --all` to see all branches related to the repo. You should be able to just use `git checkout <branch-name>`

Answer (score 1):

You are only checking your local branches when you do `git branch`

The following will show you all remote branches

```
git branch -r
```

You can create a local copy of a remote branch with

```
git checkout -b <local_name> <remote_name>
```

Comment: You don't have to use `-b` at all; if the branch is remote and you're on a newer version of Git (at least 1.7.x, I think), `git checkout <remote_name>` will both check out a local branch with that name and mark it as a tracking branch.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your second and third branches are on your remote (e.g. GitHub) as well as your local computer, you can do:

```
git checkout --track -b origin/second_branch
```

to fetch and track the remote branch on your computer.

---

If you haven't yet pushed your branches to your remote, run:

```
git push origin second_branch
```

to copy that branch to the remote so that you can pull it down using the first command.

Comment: Depending on the version of Git you have, the `--track` flag isn't necessary.